# Cakephp Password Protection with htaccess and htpasswd - howto?

Tags: .htaccess, cakephp, passwords, password-protection, .htpasswd

How can I password protect my website during development with htaccess in Cakephp?

- which htaccess file do I have to change?
- what do I have to write in the htaccess
- where do I put the .htpasswd?

I searched google for that but couldn't find anything useful, I hope you could help me!

---

Thanks Till that helped me solve the problem!

For CakePHP-Users:
- Modify the .htaccess in /app/webroot/
- add something like that at the beginning of the .htaccess-file:

```
AuthName "Restricted Area" 
AuthType Basic 
AuthUserFile /complete/path/to/.htpasswd
AuthGroupFile /dev/null 
require valid-user
```

Now create the .htpasswd-File in /app/webroot/ and drop something like this in:

```
admin:PASSWORD
```

The "PASSWORD" is a transformed version of your real password, I created it with this tool: http://tools.dynamicdrive.com/password/

I think there are much more ways to create this, but for me it worked and maybe this helps other cakephp users too.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You probably have a `.htaccess` in your document root, so you would add to this file since it's the *first* so to speak -- if you want to protect the entire website. Otherwise add a `.htaccess` file in the directory you wish to protect.

Then, check out this howto:
http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/howto/auth.html

In a nutshell, this is what you add:

```
AuthType Basic
AuthName "dev"
AuthUserFile /complete/path/to/.htpasswd
Require valid-user
```

The command to add users is:

```
htpasswd -c /complete/path/to/.htpasswd yourusername
```

Make sure you read the above howto anyway!

Comment: This doesn't work for me. It causes a 500 internal server error.

Comment: But that's because I didn't create the passwd file first.

Answer (score 0):

http://snook.ca/archives/servers/password_protect_admin/

The first link has information on using .htaccess security from within cake apps. The comments include a >hackish< workaround on how to do this for only the admin routes.